# Editing TopLinks via local.xml - changing LogOut and LogIn based on <customer_logged_in>

Tags: login, local.xml, toplinks, logout

I can't seem to get Magento to react to the **customer_logged_in** or **customer_logged_out** tags in local.xml

The LogOut link does not display unless I remove the **customer_logged_in** tag then the link displays and works correctly. I would like it to only show when the customer is logged in.

```
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links2" as="topLinks"/>         
    </reference>

    <reference name="top.links2">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links2">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
            <label>Log Out</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
            <title>Log Out</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>4</position>
            <liParams>id="top-logout"</liParams>
            <aParams/>
        </action>
    </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aw It appears I was not adding the action block in the correct layout node handle. I had the customer-logged-in and customer-logged-out nested under default.

Pulling them out of the default scope fixed the issue. This code works:

```
<default>
<reference name="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links2" as="topLinks"/>         
</reference>

<reference name="top.links2">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</default>

<customer_logged_in>
<reference name="top.links2">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
        <label>Log Out</label>
        <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
        <title>Log Out</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>4</position>
        <liParams>id="top-logout"</liParams>
        <aParams/>
    </action>
</reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

A reference for others: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Comment: I can't get this to work. I pasted it into the local.xml for my theme but it wont add that link.